# Setting default paper size for TeXLive on debian

Tags: texlive, paper-size, debian

I have TeXLive 2016 on a Debian 9.1 system.  It seems to default to A4 paper size, and I'd like to change it to letter.  I tried

```
tlmgr paper letter
```

but I get

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: action `paper' not supported in usermode
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

I don't see any option to run tlmgr not in user mode, so is there some other way to let pdftex know that I want to use letter paper by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `tlmgr` as shipped with Debian. In Debian `tlmgr` always runs in *user mode* as clearly indicated in the output.

Configuration of the TeX Live system on Debian is different from how it is done in upstream, because TeX Live has to integrate into the Debian framework.

That means, for paper configuration you need to use `paperconfig` command (as root).

Comment: sudo paperconfig -p a4 
(or letter)

Comment: ```$ sudo paperconfig --paper letter```

or

```$ sudo paperconfig --paper a4```

Answer (score 4):

In Debian the default paper size for TeXLive and other applications is supposed to be set via reconfiguring the `libpaper1` package. Either using `sudo` if it's set up, or after switching to `root` type

```
dpkg-reconfigure libpaper1
```

and select the desired `letter` paper size. This'll save it to `/etc/papersize` and run the appropriate hook which'll set up the chosen paper size for TeXLive.

Comment: Well, to be correct it should be a call to `paperconfig`

Comment: The `paperconfig` is called indirectly when `dpkg-reconfigure` is being executed.

Comment: Sure enough, because it is the correct way to adjust it. The two are the same.