# Changing default paper size for TeX Live

Tags: texlive, paper-size

I installed TeX Live. It had originally asked what I wanted the default paper size to be. I forgot to change it from A4 to Letter. Now the default paper size is A4.

How can I change the default size to Letter now that it is installed? The installation took several hours so I do not want to go through it again.

When setting a default paper size during set up what exactly happens during install?

I realize that I can specify a paper size in the header of the document but am trying to set the default to what it should have been.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the command line, you can call `tlmgr` with the `paper` option to see what the default setting is, and change it if you supply an argument. So use

```
tlmgr paper letter
```

From the [`tlmgr` documentation on `paper`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#paper):

> #### `paper`
>
> `paper [a4|letter]`
> `[xdvi|pdftex|dvips|dvipdfmx|context|psutils] paper [papersize|--list]`
> `paper --json`
>
> With no arguments (`tlmgr paper`), shows the default paper size setting for all known programs.
>
> With one argument (e.g., `tlmgr paper a4`), sets the default for all known programs to that paper size.
>
> With a program given as the first argument and no paper size specified (e.g., `tlmgr dvips paper`), shows the default paper size for that program.
>
> With a program given as the first argument and a paper size as the last argument (e.g., `tlmgr dvips paper a4`), set the default for that program to that paper size.
>
> With a program given as the first argument and `--list` given as the last argument (e.g., `tlmgr dvips paper --list`), shows all valid paper sizes for that program. The first size shown is the default.
>
> If `--json` is specified without other options, the paper setup is dumped in JSON format. For the format of JSON output see `tlpkg/doc/JSON-formats.txt`, format definition `TLPAPER`.
>
> Incidentally, this syntax of having a specific program name before the `paper` keyword is unusual. It is inherited from the longstanding `texconfig` script, which supports other configuration settings for some programs, notably `dvips`. `tlmgr` does not support those extra settings.

Comment: I get this error `tlmgr: action paper not supported in usermode`. Any ideas?

Comment: @redapemusic35: Maybe run the command prompt as administrator and try again. It may depend on how you installed TeX Live to begin with (in administrator or user mode).

Comment: I followed the directions found here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262011/105994 and then did: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389949/105994, and it worked.

Comment: I currently see same error reported by @redapemusic35 on Ubuntu 19.10.  I suspect the OS folks broke tlmgr, part of their effort to disable the package manager.  I get same error as root or as user.

Comment: Correct answer on Ubuntu 19.10 is supposed to be "$ sudo paperconfig -p letter". Will save /etc/papersize. Even after that, running pdflatex creates an A4 document.  I suspect I've got a wrong setting saved somewhere else.

Comment: On MacTex, you need to use sudo: `sudo tlmgr paper letter`.

Answer (score 5):

This is described in the [Quick install instructions](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html):

> The default is to configure the programs for the A4 paper size. To
>   make the default be 8.5x11 letter-size paper, you can use the ‘o’ menu
>   option before i(nstalling), or run `tlmgr paper letter` after
>   installation (and after setting your PATH).

Answer (score 2):

On POP! OS 22.04, this is what finally worked for me to change the paper size. Ubuntu and Debian should be the same.

First make sure the `texlive-extra-utils` package is installed. This package includes the program `texconfig-sys`.

```
sudo apt install texlive-extra-utils
```

The texlive packages include a hook for the `paperconfig` command (/etc/libpaper.d/texlive-base) to update the paper size, but it doesn't function correctly without `texconfig-sys` being installed. It's probably a packaging bug.

If you haven't run `paperconfig` yet, do it now:

```
sudo paperconfig -p letter
```

You should then see a bunch of 'tl-paper' status lines about the paper size being changed followed by a mktexlsr rebuild. If you don't get that output, the wires are crossed between the system paper size and TeX Live and you need to get the two in sync; try using `paperconfig` to change to A4 temporarily, then go back to letter.

You can also try to run `texconfig-sys` directly to change the paper size, but I find this method to be less reliable.