# Bottom margin is smaller with no reason in IEEEtran.cls

Tags: pdftex, margins, ieeetran

I"m writing a IEEE Transactions paper using the IEEEtran.cls provided by the IEEE website. With no reason the bottom margin is smaller than the one set by IEEE (and one of my reviewers noticed that). I'm writing the following code,

```
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn, twoside, journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, color, enumerate, amsthm, graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz, subcaption, cite}
\usepackage{color, xcolor, soul, bm}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
  urlcolor     = blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
  linkcolor    = blue, %Colour of internal links
  citecolor    = green %Colour of citations
}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\usepackage{epsfig} 
\usepackage{psfrag}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newcommand{\JW}[1]{{\color{red}#1}}


\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\def\endtheorem{\hspace*{\fill}~\IEEEQEDopen\par\endtrivlist\unskip}
\def\endlemma{\hspace*{\fill}~\IEEEQEDopen\par\endtrivlist\unskip}
\def\endproposition{\hspace*{\fill}~\IEEEQEDopen\par\endtrivlist\unskip}
\def\endexample{\hspace*{\fill}~\IEEEQEDopen\par\endtrivlist\unskip}
\def\endremark{\hspace*{\fill}~\IEEEQEDopen\par\endtrivlist\unskip}
\def\enddefinition{\hspace*{\fill}~\IEEEQEDopen\par\endtrivlist\unskip}
\begin{document}
\title{Security of Vehicle Platooning: A Game-Theoretic Approach}

\author{M.
\thanks{M., E-mail: {\tt \{email\}@domain}.}%
\thanks{M., E-mail: {\tt email@domain}.}
\thanks{N., E-mail: {\tt email@domain}.}
}

\newcommand{\ty}{\color{yellow}}
\newcommand{\tb}{\color{blue}}
\newcommand{\tr}{\color{red}}
\newcommand{\tg}{\color{green}}

\maketitle

\thispagestyle{empty}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{abstract}
abstract goes here ...
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
    my keywords
\end{IEEEkeywords}

My paper contents ...

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,refs}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please Clearly mention your problem area @Mohammad

Comment: Is your default paper size A4? Can you check dimensions of the pdf output? For IEEEtran the default is letterpaper (see section II.E of [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf)). But on European countries TeXLive set the default to a4paper. You can change this default with tlmgr (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/409542/132405) or use the IEEEtran class option `letterpaper` if the problem comes from this.