My Linux distribution does not supply tlmgr, hence texconfig doesn't work. How can I fix this situation?
I want to set the default paper size. This was always done using texconfig.
Unfortunately, my distribution (Suse Tumbleweed) is missing in this regard, and when I use texconfig to set the paper size I'm informed that there is no tlmgr.
I've searched, to no avail, for a RPM package including tlmgr.
Now I wonder of three options

Installing some tlmgr from a third party in /usr/local/bin.
Manually editing a few configuration files.
????

What is your advice? and, should you advice for ②, which are the relevant configuration files? is it possible to keep the extra configs in ~/.config/????

exactly what have you installed on your SuSE? I know the Ubuntu TeXLive does include tlmgr but it is limited to configuration only. Otherwise install the upstream TeXLive (see tug.org/texlive) instead.

Maybe the distribution provides paperconfig instead (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660528/)?

@Marijn I have an already installed  program called paperconf, but texconfig reports that the default paper is "letter" while "paperconf", executed w/o arguments, reports that default paper is "A4". Fortunately the PDF produced by TeX are in "A4" (according to pdfinfo, I haven't (he blushes) checked before posting) .

Maybe tlmgr is not installed or restricted to user mode to avoid collide the RPM packaging system, that probably is working with a older version, that anyway tlmgr cannot update. A solution is remove all the RPM packages related with texlive and install the new vanilla TeX Live 2024 (i.e., download the .tar.gz file a run the install script, without deal with the rpm tool).
